# Disable first form and open another form to insert data.. all this i have to do in same page?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

Disable first form and open another form to insert data.. all this i have to do in same page how to do that ?

```
        <section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="block-header">
            <h2>
                <!-- JQUERY DATATABLES
                <small>Taken from <a href="https://datatables.net/" target="_blank">datatables.net</a></small> -->
            </h2>
        </div>
        <!-- Basic Examples -->
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h2>
                            Add Amigo
                        </h2>
                        <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Something else here</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="body">


                        <!-- last row -->
                        <div class="row">                              
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                   <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="form-line">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="City Id" id="city_id">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                   <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="form-line">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="Country Id" id="country_id">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of last row -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="">Submit Details</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

here is the another section of same page

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="block-header">
            <h2>
                <!-- JQUERY DATATABLES
                <small>Taken from <a href="https://datatables.net/" target="_blank">datatables.net</a></small> -->
            </h2>
        </div>
        <!-- Basic Examples -->
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h2>
                            Add Amigo
                        </h2>
                        <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Something else here</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="body">


                        <!-- last row -->
                        <div class="row">                              
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                   <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="form-line">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="City Id" id="city_id">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                   <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="form-line">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="Country Id" id="country_id">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of last row -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="">Submit Details</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

here is the code.....when i successfully insert data after clicking submit button in first form ..i want the first form to be disable and 2 form should be enabled for inserting data !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do so using jquery :

First set the second form to be `display:none` by default then detect the function submit of the first form then show the second and hide the first using [`jQuery Effects - Fading`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp) :

> With jQuery you can fade elements in and out of visibility.
>
> jQuery [fadeIn()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein)
>
> jQuery [fadeOut()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadeout)
>
> jQuery [fadeToggle()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadetoggle)
>
> jQuery [fadeTo()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadeto)

```js
$(function(){
$('#first button').on('click',function(){
  /* your code */
 $('#first').css('pointer-events','none');
 $('#second').fadeIn();

});
$('#second button').on('click',function(){
  /* your code */
  $('#second').css('pointer-events','none');
 $('#first').fadeIn();

})
})
```

```css
section {

  Width:100%;
  height:200px;
 
}
#first {
 background-color:blue;
}
#second{
 background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="first">
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="second" style="display:none">
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: i just want to disable the first div ! not hide that??

Comment: then set `$('#first').css('pointer-events','none');` to disable the click event on that section

Comment: $('#first_name').attr("disabled","disabled");